# Line Feed not transmitted to Oracle with Attunity driver on SSIS

Tags: oracle, ssis, linefeed, character-set, attunity

I'd like to load data from Azure to an oracle database through SSIS with an Attunity driver.
Now I've noticed that the character "Line Feed" (Ascii 10) is not inserted.
When I do the same with an oledb driver instead of Attunity as destination, the character is transmitted correctly.

There seems to be a problem with the character set of this driver. Is there a way to define the character set in the connection properties of the attunity driver? Or is the reason somewhere else?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi, check this question: http://forums.attunity.com/forums/microsoft-ssis-teradata-connector/unicode-problem-using-attunity-2-0-a-2927.html There are some answers there I'd check.

Comment: Thank you for the hint - unfortunately the issue won't be solved with this answers. I've tried different conversions and the values I see in the data viewer are correct (even without a data conversion). The "ignore" of the Line Feed happens during the insert.

Additionally I've tried an ADO.NET driver and then it's working fine as well, so the cause seems really to be the attunity.